# Checking specific bits of a bitmask

Tags: python, numpy, bit-manipulation, bit, bitmask

I am working with `Bitmasks` in `python`. As far as I know, these are arrays of integers that when they are unpacked into binary format they tell you which of the 32 bits are set (=1) for a given element in the array.

I would like to know the fastest way to check whether 4 specific bits are set or not for any element of an array. I do not care about the rest. I have tried the following solution but it is not fast enough for my purpose:

```
def detect(bitmask, check=(18,22,23,24), bits=32):
    boolmask = np.zeros(len(bitmask), dtype=bool)
    for i, val in enumerate(bitmask):    
        bithost = np.zeros(bits, dtype='i1')
        masklist = list(bin(val)[2:])
        bithost[:len(masklist)] = np.flip(masklist,axis=0)
        if len(np.intersect1d(np.nonzero(bithost)[0] ,check)) != 0:
            boolmask[i] = True        
        else: 
            boolmask[i] = False
    if any(boolmask):
        print("There are some problems")
    else:
        print("It is clean")
```

For example, if a given `bitmask` contains the integer 24453656 `(1011101010010001000011000 in binary)`, the output of function ***detect*** would be "There are some problems" since bit 22 is set:

```
bit: ...  20, 21, 22, 23, 24,...  
mask: ... 0,  0,  1,  0,  0,...
```

Any ideas on how to improve the performance?

Comment: So you want to check, if  for a given integer, any of the bits you want to check, are set, and if any single one of them is set, you want to say there are problems?

Comment: Yes, that's it @Gnudiff. Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: in that case my answer should be correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integers are nothing but sequence of bits in the computer.

So, if you get integer, let's say: 333 it is a sequence of bits 101001101 to the computer. It doesn't need any unpacking into bits. It *is* bits.

Therefore, if the mask is also an integer, you don't need any unpacking, just apply bitwise operations to it. Check [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) for details of how these work.

In order to check if ANY of the bits xyz are set in an integer abc, you do:
`(abc & xyz) > 0`. If you absolutely need checking mask to be a tuple of bit places, you do some packing, like this:

```
def detect(bitmask,check=(18,22,23,24)):
    checkmask=sum(2**x for x in check)
    if (bitmask & checkmask) > 0:
        print "There are some problems"
    else:
        print "Everything OK"
```

Note that bitmasks start with 0 based bit indices. First bit is bit 0.

Comment: @JTM almost. It should've been bitmask & checkmask. Fixed, thanks

Comment: Ups, I accidentally deleted my previous comment. With this fix it works fine and faster. Thanks!

Comment: @JTM if your question is answered to your satisfaction, you are welcome to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what's in your `bitmask` argument. Regarless, you should probably use bitwise operators.

Make a bit mask like this:

```
def turn_bits_on(bits):
    n = 0
    for k in bits:
        n = (n | (1 << (k - 1))) if k > 0 else n
    return n

bits_to_check = turn_bits_on([18, 22, 23, 24])
```

Then, for a single number, you can detect with:

```
def is_ok(value, mask):
    return not (value & mask)

print(is_ok(24453656, bits_to_check))
```

Finally, depending on what your `bitmask` value is (a list, a DataFrame, etc), apply the `is_ok()` function to each value.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. As you and @Gnudiff say, the key is on the bitwise operators. I've tested both methods but his seems to perform a bit faster.