# how to decode integer bitmask to original input characters

Tags: python, bitmask

I am reading data from an application that stores optional input character flags as a packed integer (using binary packing). For sake of this discussion, use this example: `A=1, B=2, C=4, D=8, E=16` :
When the user inputs: `'AC'`, the stored value is `5 (=1+4)`
When the user inputs: `'ABCD'`, the stored value is `15 (=1+2+4+8)`
I'd like to recover the original inputs from the integer value (`5 => 'AC'` and `15 => 'ABCD'`). Case and order are not important.

I'm new at this, so read up on bitmasks and bitwise operations and wrote some working code. Basically I convert the integer to a binary value formatted as a string of 0/1s. Then I check each string position (bit) for True/False (1/0) . When True, I add the matching character to another string (from an ordered string of the input options).

My intuition tells me there's a simpler way to do this; using the binary representation as a "mask" on the check string in a single operation. I found a couple of posts that touch on bitmasking, but don't answer my question:
[Checking specific bits of a bitmask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53724160)
[How to take bit number 3 from 8 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56018322)

Is it possible to simplify the code below?
It works for all values of i_flag = 1 thru 31.
[I know I need error checking for invalid i_flag values (`=0` and `>(n_char**2)-1`)
I will add that once I have the conversion logic set.]

```
chk_str = 'EDCBA'
i_flag = 1
str_flag=''
b_flag = ('{:0'+str(len(chk_str))+'b}').format(i_flag)
for pos in range(len(b_flag)) :
   if int(b_flag[pos]):
       str_flag += chk_str[pos]

print ('for int=', i_flag, ',flags are:',str_flag)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cool way of dealing with this would be to create a generic `BitMask`:

```
import string
import itertools


class BitMask(object):
    STR_TOKENS = string.ascii_letters
    STR_EMPTY = '_'
    STR_FULL = False

    def __init__(
            self,
            value=None,
            ignore=True):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            self.value = self.from_tokens(value, self.STR_TOKENS, ignore)
        else:
            self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return bin(self.value)

    def __iter__(self):
        value = self.value
        while value:
            yield value & 1
            value >>= 1

    def to_tokens(self, tokens, empty, full):
        if full:
            return [
                token if value else empty
                for token, value in
                itertools.zip_longest(tokens, self, fillvalue=False)]
        else:
            return [
                token for token, value in zip(tokens, self) if value]

    def __str__(self):
        return ''.join(
            self.to_tokens(self.STR_TOKENS, self.STR_EMPTY, self.STR_FULL))

    def from_tokens(self, seq, tokens, ignore):
        if tokens is None:
            tokens = self.STR_TOKENS
        valid_tokens = set(tokens)
        value = 0
        for i, item in enumerate(seq):
            if item in valid_tokens:
                value |= 1 << tokens.index(item)
            elif not ignore:
                raise ValueError(f'Invalid input `{item}` at index: {i}.')
        return value

    def __add__(self, other):
        self.value |= other.value
        return self

    def __mul__(self, other):
        self.value &= other.value
        return self

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return type(self) == type(other) and self.value == other.value
```

which you can subclass to your need, e.g.:

```
class MyBitMask(BitMask):
    STR_TOKENS = string.ascii_uppercase
    def __init__(self, value=None, ignore=False):
        super().__init__(value, ignore)


print(str(MyBitMask(5)))
# AC
print(str(MyBitMask(15)))
# ABCD
```

but also:

```
repr(MyBitMask('AC'))
# 0b101

MyBitMask('AC') == MyBitMask(5)
# True

MyBitMask('AC') == BitMask(5)  # NOT THE SAME BITMASK CLASS!
# False
```

Timewise, coolness costs speed, i.e. (comparing with the methods from the other answers):

```
def convert(value, tokens=string.ascii_uppercase):
    output = ''
    i = 0
    while value:
        if value & 1:
            output += tokens[i]
        i += 1
        value >>= 1
    return output


def convert2(value, tokens=string.ascii_uppercase):
    return ''.join(tokens[i] for i, c in enumerate(bin(value)[:1:-1]) if c == '1')


def convert3(value, tokens=string.ascii_uppercase):
    result = []
    i = 0
    while value:
        if value & 1:
            result.append(tokens[i])
        i += 1
        value >>= 1
    return ''.join(result)


def convert4(value, tokens=string.ascii_uppercase):
    return ''.join(tokens[pos] for pos in range(value.bit_length()) if value & (1 << pos))


def convert5(value, tokens=string.ascii_uppercase):
    return ''.join(c for b, c in zip(reversed('{:b}'.format(value)), tokens) if b == '1')

print([convert(i) for i in range(16)])
print([convert2(i) for i in range(16)])
print([convert3(i) for i in range(16)])
print([convert4(i) for i in range(16)])
print([convert5(i) for i in range(16)])
print([str(MyBitMask(i)) for i in range(16)])
# ['', 'A', 'B', 'AB', 'C', 'AC', 'BC', 'ABC', 'D', 'AD', 'BD', 'ABD', 'CD', 'ACD', 'BCD', 'ABCD']
```

```
%timeit [convert(i) for i in range(1024)]
%timeit [convert2(i) for i in range(1024)]
%timeit [convert3(i) for i in range(1024)]
%timeit [convert4(i) for i in range(1024)]
%timeit [convert5(i) for i in range(1024)]
%timeit [str(MyBitMask(i)) for i in range(1024)]
```

```
1.8 ms ± 5.45 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
2.11 ms ± 83.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
2.29 ms ± 331 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
3.42 ms ± 1.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
2.24 ms ± 103 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
4.48 ms ± 151 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: norok2, thanks for the elegant BitMask class and running the timing tests for all the suggested answers. All very helpful. I do this _very occasionally_ (thus my ignorance), and only have to convert a few variables one time per run (so, a msec here or there doesn't matter). For me, simpler is better  because I need to understand the code the next time I read it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `while` loop instead to keep shifting the input integer value by 1 bit until it becomes 0, and for each iteration append to the output the character in the current position of the mapping string if the lowest bit of the integer is 1:

```
def convert(i):
    output = ''
    pos = 0
    while i:
        if i & 1:
            output += 'ABCDE'[pos]
        pos += 1
        i >>= 1
    return output
```

so that `convert(5)` returns `'AC'`, and `convert(15)` returns `'ABCD'`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the number to binary (and ignore the first 2 chars which would be '0x') and 
pick the chars from the alphabet that correspond to bits that are set

```
>>> import string
>>> n = 5
>>> ''.join(string.ascii_uppercase[i] for i,c in enumerate(bin(n)[:1:-1]) if c=='1')
'AC'
>>> 
>>> n = 15
>>> ''.join(string.ascii_uppercase[i] for i,c in enumerate(bin(n)[:1:-1]) if c=='1')
'ABCD'
>>> 
>>> n = 2
>>> ''.join(string.ascii_uppercase[i] for i,c in enumerate(bin(n)[:1:-1]) if c=='1')
'B'
```

Comment: `n = 2` seems wrong to me, should be `bin(n)[:1:-1]` not `bin(n)[2:]`

Comment: sorry. got confused by the symmetric nature of the binary form of 5 and 15. Updated the answer

Comment: Interesting solution. I don't see how are you set the characters to check. I used ABCDE in the example, but options could be anything (ADXZ, or BKTY)

Comment: @kcw78 that is `string.ascii_uppercase`

Comment: ok, thanks for explaining. I'm not familiar with `enumerate(), so will have to go thru it step-by-step to understand how it works.

Comment: @norok2 I should clarify my comment about this solution. My example has ABCDE as my flags, but it could be any set of letters. What if the flag options are BDKX?  I see how this is handled by adding `tokens=` to the input parameters in your answer below. Very good. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can convert the input integer value to a binary string first with the `str.format` method, reverse it, and then `zip` it with the mapping string so that you can use a generator expression to filter out bits that are not `1`, before you join the remaining characters into a string:

```
def convert(i):
    return ''.join(c for b, c in zip(reversed('{:b}'.format(i)), 'ABCDE') if b == '1')
```

so that `convert(5)` returns `'AC'`, and `convert(15)` returns `'ABCD'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate a bit offset over the bit length of the input integer, and test each bit accordingly:

```
def convert(i):
    return ''.join('ABCDE'[pos] for pos in range(i.bit_length()) if i & (1 << pos))
```

so that `convert(5)` returns `'AC'`, and `convert(15)` returns `'ABCD'`.